# How does one modify the memory of another application on Android without RootAccess

Tags: android, c++, memory

According to my knowledge memory modification is blocked on Android since any memory trace function requires Root Access.
There is an application on Play Store that modifies a certain game.
How does the application do that?
Does it run some sort of headless VM that it has memory control over?